# Does Android Studio support simulations with RTT for FTM?

Tags: android, android-studio, rtti

I am trying to run the following GitHub repo https://github.com/darryncampbell/WiFi-RTT-Trilateration on my laptop. According to the documentation of the project, the simulation is done using a Pixel 2XL running >= Android Pie/Android 10.

- Are the Access Points simulated by Android Studio?

In my experience, when I try to run the project and start ranging every combination displays the error 'This device does not support RTT'. I tried the following combinations: Google Pixel 2 with Android Pie & Android 10, Google Pixel 2XL with Android Pie & Android 10, and Google Pixel 3 with Android Pie & Android 10 (none of them worked).

Why does RTT seem not to work?

[image: here's a picture of the error I am getting]